# Displying mysql stored timestamp values on the browser

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to display mysql stored unix timestamp values on my browser (and also save them to a CSV file). The values are stored as int (11). The problem is that when I display them, I see  'd', 'P', 'j', 'M' and other characters that are used for formatting dates instead of the actual timestamp. What's going wrong ?

```
<?php

/* MySQL connection and database connection code */
mysql_query ("SELECT emailaddress, subscribedate FROM email_list_subscribers WHERE subscriberid = '$sid'");

$email_result= mysql_query ("SELECT emailaddress, subscribedate FROM  email_list_subscribers WHERE subscriberid = '$sid'");
if (mysql_num_rows ($email_result) == 0) {
  $email = '';
  $subscribedate = '';
} else {
  $email = mysql_fetch_assoc ($email_result);
  $email =  $email['emailaddress'];
  $subscribedate = (string) ( $email['subscribedate']);
  echo $sid . " : " . $subscribedate . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Show us the PHP code you tried.

Comment: Sure. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/ktJZFRpS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the timestamp value to a datetime in order to show the formated info:

```
    $timestamp = '1348617600';

    $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

    echo $datetime;
```

also you can use:

```
echo strtotime($timestamp);
```

**Be careful, you have to take into account the timezone**

Comment: Well thing is I don't want to format it, just want to display the integer timestamp as it is. It is rather strange that I'm getting these strange characters trying to display a 11 digit int.

Comment: Assuming that you have the timestamp inside a php variable you can just do an echo $timestamp; or for double checking that it will be formatted as a string i would recommend you echo sprintf('%s',$timestamp);

Comment: Here's something strange I've noticed. When I try to convert '1346099654' to time using strtotime, I get a boolean false on this server. Why would that be ?